# Ajax - displaying xml message in html page

Tags: ajax, xml

When sending a message, the xml displays in the debugger. But I am not sure how to display it in the html webpage. I am not using jquery

```
    if(xhr) {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                var value = xhr.responseXML;
                var msgs = value.getElementsByTagName('message');
                console.log("Processing ", msgs.length, " messages");
                for(var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    var id = parseInt(msgs[i].getAttribute("id"));
                    if(lastid < id) {
                        lastid = id;
                    }
                    console.log(msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);


                }
```

Do I need to add anything else to the above and what do I need to put on my html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is actually only a little JavaScript code which writes some result to the console (console.log).

from this i can't see what you really want to do, but to write to the document instead of the console you can use document.write(msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);

or if you specify a DIV with the id="res" for example, then you can do

```
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

instead of

```
console.log(msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Comment: thanks that displays all the messages, is there any way to just dislay the most recent message rather than all of them?

Comment: sure, change the += to a simple = so then you will not append the html but change it to the most recent every time

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = msgs[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue
```

Or in other words, you need to set the text, which should be display, as text content of an element. If it is a new one you need to append it to the dom. All in all: it depends on your way to display the message. It is also possible to use client-side templates like [moustache](http://mustache.github.io/) if displaying becomes more complex.